# R How to convert factor to double

Tags: r, decimal, factors

found some related topics but still not sure how to deal with this particular case:
I read in a data frame from a csv. Now I have one variable/column, `x`, that was read in as a `factor`. However, the values it contains are of the Kind "100,50" which I would like to have as `numeric/double` in order to be able to operate with the numbers.

`as.numeric(as.character(x))` replaces most of the elements in `x` to `NA`.

How do I transfer the different levels of `x` to actual numbers? the separator is ','.
Thanks in advance! I appreciate any help

Comment: But may be you can set decimal point when get your data. Show how you  "read in a data frame from a csv"

Comment: `read.table` got a `dec` parameter. Use it.

Comment: @Batanichek You should set `fixed = TRUE` if you use `gsub` for this.

Comment: @Roland Thanks  `as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",",".","100,50",fixed=TRUE))`

Comment: so this would mean `x<-as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",",".",x,fixed=TRUE))` ?  (sry for multiple edits, fighting troubles with my connection)